# How to fix Drupal website log in problem

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, content-management-system

I have a problem with drupal login action. I cannot log in to the drupal site i'm working on.

I've tried to log in as admin and other user in different browser, cleared browser cache ann tried, and i'm still not able to log in.

Has anyone else come across same problem??

what must be done to remedy this?

Does anyone know what causes this problem??

Comment: check that the cookie received from the website is not containing a path or a bad domain (use firebug or LiveHTTP Headers) -- check as well you have the right password :-)

Comment: :-) no the pswd is rite, let me check the cookie.

Comment: Did you check log files and dblog table if something was written?

Comment: i am not logged in as a admin now, am trying repeatedly to login, then did not find any issue with cookie.. am not much of an expert, so if you could pls explain to me more precisely what might cause this and what all must i try.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/78953 maybe that page will help

Comment: mm saw a comment to delete recent history there, so removed that n cookies, now its working again!! any idea y it happened.

Comment: Download `drush`, the indespensible `DRUpal SHell` and you can begin to triage using: `drush -u 1 status`. Which will check on the status of your administrative account.

Comment: ok i dint get fully what that is , but thanks i ll look into it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried accessing the user table via PHPMyAdmin and resetting the password and then attempting to login?